# how to create a countdown for a date given in a different view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, date, uidatepicker, countdown

Hey I have an initial screen that comes up when the app is launched the first time or when edit button is clicked, I will be taking a target date from the user using a date picker.
How can I then do a countdown on the home screen to this given date??
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Add NSTimer and use this two variables
    NSTimeInterval start =  [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval end =    [selectedDate timeIntervalSince1970];

Answer (score 0):

You could use  `timeIntervalSince` like this;

```
NSDate *chosenDate;

// Time interval between future date and todays date
NSTimeInterval *intervalInSeconds = [chosenDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate Date]];
```

Then you convert it to the units of your choice like this;

[How can I calculate the difference between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371757/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like are asking asking about how to share a property between screens.  There are a couple approaches to this.

1. Put the date property in your appDelegate
2. Give your initial screen a reference to the home screen
3. Give your home screen a reference to the initial screen
4. Create a singleton that manages data for you.