# Finding the difference between two dates always prints 10

Tags: ios, objective-c

Following is my code to get current date.

```
-(NSString *) getCurrentDate {
    NSDateFormatter *dateformater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateformater setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    NSString *today=[dateformater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    return today;
}
```

Im using the following code to find the difference between current date and the date selected from pickerview

```
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
  NSString *date = [dateFormat stringFromDate:picker.date];
  NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:GregorianCalendar];
  NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |  NSCalendarUnitDay;
  NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [f setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
  NSDate *selectedDate = [f dateFromString:date];
  NSDate *currentDate = [f dateFromString:[self getCurrentDate]];
  NSDateComponents *currentDateComponent = [gregorianCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:currentDate toDate:selectedDate options:0];
```

but the `currentDateComponent.day` always prints the value 10.

whats wrong with my code? how can i be able to find the difference between two dates?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371757/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates

Comment: i have tried it though

Comment: Those whole code can be simplified as `NSDateComponents *currentDateComponent = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:picker.date options:0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think components you are using is wrong it should but only NSCalendarUnitDay
My code is returning me correct difference (difference.day).

```
 NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
 NSDateComponents *difference = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                           fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:enDate options:0];
```