# Calculating Number of days between 2 datepickers

Tags: ios

For iOS, how does one calculate the number of days between two dates generated by two different date pickers?

Comment: UIDatePicker has a date parameter.  Take the date from each, and refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723431/swift-days-between-two-nsdates for the rest.

Comment: I tried to use this method, but I was unable to get it to work:  var days = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components: Set<Calendar.Components>, from: Date, to: Date). Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: If it's still not working after, post a snippet of your attempt  so we can debug it.  It's hard to understand the context without any code.

Comment: Thanks so much.  It now works.  I tried to post a snippet, but unsure how.  Need to learn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the difference between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371757/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates)